# Retrofit/Gson error: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1

Tags: python, android, postgresql, flask, retrofit2

I am trying to fetch data from by postgres database and then send the data to my app. I am using Retrofit to communicate with my Flask API to access and query the database.

For my data request I want to get multiple objects from my database.
For testing I am currently using

```
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM TestDB')
    Testdata = cursor.fetchall()
    print(Testdata)
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    return jsonify(Testdata )
```

Based on the tutorials I found online this gets the data and then sends the data as json as a response.

in the app I have

```
interface TestAPI{
    @GET("getTest")
    fun getTest(@Query("T1") lat: Double, @Query("T2") lon: Double, @Query("T3") range: Double): Call<TestResponse>

data class TestResponse(val TestList : List<TestPin>) {
    @SerializedName("Tests")
    val tests : List<TestPin> = TestList
}
```

However in my app I get the following error in Retrofit / Gson: "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1"

Based on the error and my google search the error appears to be that I am sending an array / list to my app but Gson expects only one element.

I found several questions already on stackoverflow and other sites with the same error and also a similar problem.
For most people the solution was to chagne the Call response to a list, which I did (see code above;  TestResponse is a List of TestPin).

But this did not fix my problem. I even tried to change the Call response to List

```
interface TestAPI{
    @GET("getTest")
    fun getTest(@Query("T1") lat: Double, @Query("T2") lon: Double, @Query("T3") range: Double): Call<List<TestPin>>
```

I (might) also have another problem with the JSON generation which might be linked to the problem above.

When I print out my JSON response or write it to a json file I get an array of my objects:

[(1, 'Test', '010100000085EB51B81E0524400000000000B49840', 'Monday', 'Tueday', 'wed'),(2, 'Test2', '010100000085EB51B81E0524400000000000B49840', 'Monday', 'Tueday', 'wed')]

However I expected to get a more json like formated response with the column names as content headers:

[(id: "1", name:'Test', pos: '010100000085EB51B81E0524400000000000B49840', Day1: 'Monday', Day2: 'Tueday', Day3: 'wed')]

I don't know if this is connected with my other provlem and I tried several "solutions" found on stackoverflow but I could not get the column headers into the response.

I found a lot of questions already on stack overflow with similar errors, especially "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1".

But either the answer used a completly different approach or it did not work for me.

I am quite new to working with Flask, Postgres and Retrofit and it mioght be something very obvious. I hope that someone can show me where my mistake or misunderstanding lies.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To fix this issue, you need to adjust your Retrofit interface and response classes accordingly.  Check your data class.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve the problem on my own.

After some more trial and error, I discovered that the problem lies in the database response.
The JSON response was not correctly formated.
After changing that it worked